# how can I put 3 internal borders to a single div with differents width and border-color? should I create 3 divs and each one with its own properties?

Tags: css

There are 3 `borders` (*green,white, internal border black I suggest*) and each one with its color and `border-radius`.
I don't know if I should create 3 `divs` and to each one put the `border` properties and if on the contrary everything can be done in the same `div`.

basically I have this design:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxv8J.png

I would like to know the best way to do it, thank you very much.

this is my idea:

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.border1{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  border:20px solid green; 
  border-radius: 20px;

}

.border2{
  border:15px solid white; 
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content{
 background:black;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="border1">
  <div class="border2">
    <div class="content">
      <span>Growth</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the borders are purely decorative you could use pseudo before and after elements to produce the white and green rather than put extra elements into the actual HTML.

This snippet sets the width of the green and while borders and the distance between the whole thing and the edge of the viewport as CSS variables and uses CSS calc function to place a white before pseudo element and a green after pseudo element behind the black one. That way you can get 3 different radii as required.

Obviously you will want to change the radii in this code to suit your particular need.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

.borders {
  --greenW: 30px;
  --whiteW: 10px;
  --edge: 20px;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% - (2 * (var(--greenW) + var(--whiteW) + var(--edge))));
  height: calc(100% - (2 * (var(--greenW) + var(--whiteW) + var(--edge))));
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW) + var(--edge));
  top: calc(var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW) + var(--edge));
}

.borders::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% + (2 * var(--whiteW)));
  height: calc(100% + (2 * var(--whiteW)));
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--whiteW));
  left: calc(-1 * var(--whiteW));
  z-index: -1;
}

.borders::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% + (2 * (var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW))));
  height: calc(100% + (2 * (var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW))));
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(-1 * (var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW)));
  left: calc(-1 * (var(--whiteW) + var(--greenW)));
  border-radius: 40px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="borders">Growth</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with only `border`. I used `box-shadow` and `border` for this.

```css
body {
 background:#dadada;
}

#bordered {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px #00ff1c , inset 0px 0px 0px 10px black;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bordered"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you've have to use Multiple Boxes and Containers to achieve this.
Use the following Snippet to understand it better.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.module {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #555;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  margin: 20px;
}

.module:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
</div>
```

Comment: Understand how it works and you can implement your own here.

Comment: thanks for your answer... what I don't know what to do is how to put the radius border to the different borders.